# scroll up/down jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to scroll down to a div in my page, and then scroll a bit up.

using jquery.

I got this onclick bind:

```
{
 $.scrollTo( $('#theDestDiv'), 1000);
 window.scrollTo(0, (window.pageYOffset)-100 );
}
```

Problem is: the window.scroll fires before the page finishes the scroll to theDestDiv
and then the pageYOffset gets the wrong value.

I tried setTimeout and that works only if the timeout is for the time it takes to scroll down.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Which `scrollTo plugin are you using (because there is more than one)?

Comment: Not sure about the plugin, but this kinda works:             $.scrollTo( $('#theDisclaimer'), 1000);
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '-=50'});                            The scroll reaches the destination and the scrolls 50 px up. if there is another way, without scrolling twice, please add.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jquery's animation complete callback function? You can have code run after the animation is complete. Below is an example.

```
var scrollTo = $('#theDestDiv').offset(); //find the target
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollTo}, 1000, function(){
    //on animation complete, scroll back up
    var scrollUp = scrollTo.top-100;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollUp}, 1000);
});
```

If you're trying to give it a sort of 'bounce', I would recommend using the jquery.easing plugin instead. The easing you would want to use is easeOutBack so that the animation passes its final position and returns back slowly. http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.scrollTo( $('#theDisclaimer'), 1000);
scroll_up_disclaimer();

function scroll_up_disclaimer(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:"-=68"})
}
```